# How to get specific return type from Generic

Tags: java, generic-programming

I have class Attribute

```
class Attribute{
private Parser parser;
private String value;
private ParserType parseType;
}
```

and Enum

```
Enum ParserType{
STRING,NUMBER,RANGE
}
```

and parser interface

```
interface Parser<S,T>{
 T parse(S s){
}
}
```

now for based on different data type i am parsing value in different way. So for that i created classes

```
class StringParser implements Parser<String,String>{

@override
public String parse(String value){
return //... parse and return string
}
```

In similar way i have other parser

```
 class DoubleParser implements Parser<String,Double>{

@override
public Double parse(String value){
return //... parse and return double
}
```

What i am doing here is having reference of Parser in **Attribute** and setting different type of parser based on its **ParserType**

for example

```
class Attribute{
private Parser parser;
private String value;
private ParserType parseType;

Attribute(String value,ParserType parsertype){
 this.value=value;
 this.parserType=parserType
 }

private void setParserType()
 {
 switch(parserType){
  case ParserType.String:
   parser=new StringParser();
  break;

  case ParserType.Number:
  parser=new NumberParser();
  break;
 }

 }

  public void parse(){
  parser.parse(value); // here return type is object...  and i want it to be String if it is StringParser and bouble if it is DoubleParser
  }
}
```

if you see **parse()** method in **Attribute** class. I want it to give String data type if it is **StringParser** and double if it is **DoubleParser**

I know i am doing something wrong there using generics. So my question is What is the best practice to achieve this?

**UPDATED**

Thanks for Answer guys.. But Now i want to store that **Attribute** in a Map but when i do something like this it return me **Object**

```
// I did changes in my Attribute class 
public T parse(){
return parser.parse(value); // here return type is object...  and i want it to be String if it is StringParser and bouble if it is DoubleParser
}

Map<String,Attribute> map;
//assuming my map has some entries
for(Map.Entry<String,Attribute> m:map.entrySet()){
 map.getValue().parse(); // this parse methods returns object to me here. I want it to be some specific type like String or Double
}
```

Comment: is the Parser#parse always going to take String as parameter?

Comment: in most cases it will have String. But we are at initial stage of or project so cant say. Depending on case we have to change it

Answer (score 1):

Provide your return type while creating object of `Attribute.java`

**Parser.java**

```
interface Parser<S,T>{
     T parse(S s);
}
```

**StringParser.java**

```
public class StringParser<S> implements Parser<String, S>{
    @Override
    public S parse(String s) {
        return (S) "Hello";
    }
}
```

**DoubleParser.java**

```
public class DoubleParser<S> implements Parser<Double, S>{
    @Override
    public S parse(Double s) {
        return (S) new Double(1);
    }
}
```

**Attribute.java**

```
public class Attribute<T, R> {
    public T value;
    private Parser<T, R> parser;

    public Attribute(T value, String parserType) {
        switch (parserType) {
        case "ParserTypeString":
            parser = (Parser<T, R>) new StringParser<R>();
            break;
        case "ParserTypeNumber":
            parser = (Parser<T, R>) new DoubleParser<R>();
            break;
        }

    }

    public R parseReturn() {
        return parser.parse(value);
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Attribute<String, String> str = new Attribute<String, String>("World", "ParserTypeString");
        System.out.println(str.parseReturn());

        Attribute<Double, Double> dbl = new Attribute<Double, Double>(5D, "ParserTypeNumber");
        System.out.println(dbl.parseReturn());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
class Attribute<T, R> {

    private final T value;

    private final Parser<T, R> parser;

    public Attribute(T value, Parser<T, R> parser) {
        this.value = value;
        this.parser = parser;
    }

    private R parse() {
        return parser.parse(value);
    }

    private interface Parser<T, R> {
        R parse(T t);
    }

    private static class StringParser implements Parser<String, String> {
        @Override
        public String parse(String s) {
            return s;
        }
    }

    private static class DoubleParser implements Parser<String, Double> {
        @Override
        public Double parse(String s) {
            return Double.parseDouble(s);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Attribute<String, String> stringAttribute = new Attribute<>("input", new StringParser());
        Attribute<String, Double> doubleAttribute = new Attribute<>("1.0", new DoubleParser());

        System.out.println(stringAttribute.parse()); //should print the string
        System.out.println(doubleAttribute.parse()); //prints the double value
    }
}
```

Note - I have added all the interfaces and classes in the same class to keep the example in a single file for you to copy and run without creating multiple files.

I also changed the structure a little to make it more readable. You can provide the parsers during construction of the attribute class rather than keeping the ParserType in the class and then deciding what parser to instantiate. Attribute class should not be responsible for doing that.

Comment: Don't edit your question, post a new question since now you are asking additional stuff. Anyway your edited question doesn't make much sense.